# Golang archive/zip producing corrupt files with Pipes

Tags: go, zip

I'm trying to pull files from a MinIO file storage instance, zip the files, and push the zip files back to minio.  I've gotten most of it working, but for some reason the zip file that ends up in the storage is corrupted e.g. `file testzip.zip` shows that it is a zip file, but unzipping does not work:

```
Archive:  somerandomname.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of somerandomname.zip or
    somerandomname.zip.zip, and cannot find somerandomname.zip.ZIP, period.
```

**This is the code**

```
func testThis() error {
pipeReader, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()

zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(pipeWriter)
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(2)

go func() {

    defer wg.Done()
    defer zipWriter.Close()
    defer pipeWriter.Close()

    header := &zip.FileHeader{
        Name:         "testzip.zip",
        Method:       zip.Deflate,
        ModifiedTime: uint16(time.Now().UnixNano()),
        ModifiedDate: uint16(time.Now().UnixNano()),
    }

    fw, err := zipWriter.CreateHeader(header)


    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err")
    }

    object, err := minioClient.GetObject("test", "somekey", minio.GetObjectOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(fw, object); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}()

go func() {
    defer wg.Done()

    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, pipeReader); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }

    _, err := minioClient.PutObject("test", "testzip.zip", pipeReader, -1, minio.PutObjectOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}()

wg.Wait()

return nil
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to close `zipWriter` *before* closing `pipeWriter`. Your two `defer()` calls are in that order, but deferred calls happen in the opposite order, so you're closing `pipeWriter` before closing `zipWriter`. The trailer therefore never makes it out. It's probably wise to check for errors from the close functions, even if all you can do is log them: that would have caught this, as the trailer-write would fail.

Comment: If you copy the zip file to stdout you cannot upload it to minio afterward (the file will be empty). Use a [TeeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) or [MultiWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter) instead.